# bulk node save for Drupal computed fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

Trying to calculate a (new) computed field on over 200 existing nodes.

I've tried bulk saving them using VBO's

- Save post (node_save_action)
- Execute arbitrary PHP script & node_save($object);
- Execute arbitrary PHP script & the customized version of this: http://drupal.org/node/905814#comment-3513678

... none of these update the computed field. Saving each node manually does.

Is there a way to accomplish this in bulk?

EDIT: VBO's Execute arbitrary PHP script & node_save($object); does update the node, but does not update the node's term array when one term is deleted. Only manually editing/saving the node does that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this issue:

http://drupal.org/node/195013

Also, you could try using the Save action with Views Bulk Operations.

Comment: thanks - I already tried both of those in items 1 and 2. It's looking like it's a different problem - a term was deleted, but the node's delta values in the term array are not updating unless the node is manually saved.